# T-SQL Group By union? with unique step ids per group

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to create unique step id for each step name group and if the step name group repeats, it gets a new number.

```
Step Name   Process Time                        Step ID     Step Name   Process Time            
----------  -----------------------             ----------  ----------  -----------------------
Prep        2018-02-26 12:00:00.000             1           Prep        2018-02-26 12:00:00.000
Prep        2018-02-26 12:00:10.000             1           Prep        2018-02-26 12:00:10.000
Wash        2018-02-26 12:00:20.000             2           Wash        2018-02-26 12:00:20.000
Wash        2018-02-26 12:00:30.000             2           Wash        2018-02-26 12:00:30.000
Dry         2018-02-26 12:00:40.000             3           Dry         2018-02-26 12:00:40.000
Dry         2018-02-26 12:00:50.000             3           Dry         2018-02-26 12:00:50.000
Wash        2018-02-26 12:01:00.000             4           Wash        2018-02-26 12:01:00.000
Wash        2018-02-26 12:01:10.000     ===>    4           Wash        2018-02-26 12:01:10.000
Break       2018-02-26 12:01:20.000             5           Break       2018-02-26 12:01:20.000
Prep        2018-02-26 12:01:30.000             6           Prep        2018-02-26 12:01:30.000
Wash        2018-02-26 12:01:40.000             7           Wash        2018-02-26 12:01:40.000
Dry         2018-02-26 12:01:50.000             8           Dry         2018-02-26 12:01:50.000
Dry         2018-02-26 12:02:00.000             8           Dry         2018-02-26 12:02:00.000
Dry         2018-02-26 12:02:10.000             8           Dry         2018-02-26 12:02:10.000
Dry         2018-02-26 12:02:20.000             8           Dry         2018-02-26 12:02:20.000
Finish      2018-02-26 12:02:30.000             9           Finish      2018-02-26 12:02:30.000
```

The table records are dynamically generated and no way to know what step name will be as it's user entered text.

I was thinking using:

```
select 
    CASE WHEN LAG([Step Name]) OVER (ORDER BY [Process Time]) = [Step Name]
         THEN 'var'
          ELSE 'var+1'
    END as [Step ID]

,*
from #example_1 ORDER BY [Process Time] ASC;
```

Gives me something like,

```
Step ID     Step Name   Process Time            
----------  ----------  -----------------------
int+1       Prep        2018-02-26 12:00:00.000
int         Prep        2018-02-26 12:00:10.000
int+1       Wash        2018-02-26 12:00:20.000
int         Wash        2018-02-26 12:00:30.000
int+1       Dry         2018-02-26 12:00:40.000
int         Dry         2018-02-26 12:00:50.000
int+1       Wash        2018-02-26 12:01:00.000
int         Wash        2018-02-26 12:01:10.000
int+1       Break       2018-02-26 12:01:20.000
int+1       Prep        2018-02-26 12:01:30.000
int+1       Wash        2018-02-26 12:01:40.000
int+1       Dry         2018-02-26 12:01:50.000
int         Dry         2018-02-26 12:02:00.000
int         Dry         2018-02-26 12:02:10.000
int         Dry         2018-02-26 12:02:20.000
int+1       Finish      2018-02-26 12:02:30.000
```

but i am not sure how to actually +1 a var in a select as its not a loop per se..
Inbuilt group functions did not produce results im happy with so im kinda stuck.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are looking foor [DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql)

Comment: Tried that. It gives separated step names the same id. Not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `lag` and `sum() over(order by ...)`. `Lag` marks cases where two consecutive `Step Names` does not match. And `sum` forms needed `Step ID`

```
declare @t table (
    [Step Name]   varchar(100)
    , [Process Time] datetime
)
insert into @t values
    ('Prep', '20180226 12:00:00.000'), ('Prep', '20180226 12:00:10.000')
    , ('Wash', '20180226 12:00:20.000'), ('Wash', '20180226 12:00:30.000')
    , ('Dry', '20180226 12:00:40.000'), ('Dry', '20180226 12:00:50.000')
    , ('Wash', '20180226 12:01:00.000'), ('Wash', '20180226 12:01:10.000')
    , ('Break', '20180226 12:01:20.000'), ('Prep', '20180226 12:01:30.000')
    , ('Wash', '20180226 12:01:40.000'), ('Dry', '20180226 12:01:50.000')
    , ('Dry', '20180226 12:02:00.000'), ('Dry', '20180226 12:02:10.000')
    , ('Dry', '20180226 12:02:20.000'), ('Finish', '20180226 12:02:30.000')


select
    [Step ID] = sum(grp) over (order by [Process Time]), [Step Name], [Process Time]
from (
    select
        *, grp = iif([Step Name] = lag([Step Name]) over (order by [Process Time]), 0, 1)
    from
        @t
) t
order by [Process Time]
```

Output:

```
Step ID    Step Name    Process Time
-----------------------------------------------
1          Prep         2018-02-26 12:00:00.000
1          Prep         2018-02-26 12:00:10.000
2          Wash         2018-02-26 12:00:20.000
2          Wash         2018-02-26 12:00:30.000
3          Dry          2018-02-26 12:00:40.000
3          Dry          2018-02-26 12:00:50.000
4          Wash         2018-02-26 12:01:00.000
4          Wash         2018-02-26 12:01:10.000
5          Break        2018-02-26 12:01:20.000
6          Prep         2018-02-26 12:01:30.000
7          Wash         2018-02-26 12:01:40.000
8          Dry          2018-02-26 12:01:50.000
8          Dry          2018-02-26 12:02:00.000
8          Dry          2018-02-26 12:02:10.000
8          Dry          2018-02-26 12:02:20.000
9          Finish       2018-02-26 12:02:30.000
```

Comment: very nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a workaround but you can use this:

```
    ;WITH T (StepName ,  ProcessTime) 
    AS
     (     
    SELECT 'Prep' , '2018-02-26 12:00:00.000'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Prep' , '2018-02-26 12:00:10.000'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Wash' , '2018-02-26 12:00:20.000'       
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Wash' , '2018-02-26 12:00:30.000'
    )

    , Ids as 
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) Seq  , StepName
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT  StepName
        FROM T
        ) P
    )


    SELECT t.StepName , t.ProcessTime ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T.StepName ORDER BY T.StepName) + I.Seq -1 StepId
     FROM T 
     JOIN Ids i
     ON T.StepName = I.StepName
     ORDER BY StepId , ProcessTime
```

Comment: Keep in mind the table is dynamically generated and step names might be different. Regardless DENSE_RANK() does not produce split grouping, as my the output using the method is not exactly right. Unless im not understanding something here?

Comment: In this method you simply construct a sequence per every step name and then rank (dense rank) by the name and add the sequence you've constructed, it will work for every step name that will be generated. the thing is that the enumeration will be based upon your step name and it might not be generating the exact order you wish to display it